# Strange difference between what PHP tells me is a error and my code Insert into Mysql Table?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Hello I am doing some simple inserting into a table from my `<php>` and it doesn't work let me start off with the code:

```
<?php
include_once "connect.php";
$db_host="localhost";
$user_name="root";
$pass="";
$db_name="knight orders";
$con = mysql_connect("$db_host","$user_name","$pass") or die("There is a problem with the connection");
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$con) or die("There is a problem with the database");
$name="Default";
$rank=3;
//$name=$_POST['name'];
//$rank=$_POST['rank'];
$table_name="ordertemp";
$query="INSERT INTO '$table_name' ('Code','Name')VALUES ('$rank','$name')";
mysql_query($query,$con) or die("Problems!" . mysql_error());
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

I'm working with some default values now but I will be reading from a form later, the strange thing is when I check out the `mysql_error()` result in Firefox it tells me:

`Problems!You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''ordertemp' ('Code','Name')VALUES ('3','Default')' at line 1`

It's changing some of the semicolons, could this be what causes my error, or if you've seen other faults please point them out.

Comment: Remove single quotes covering $table_name n you are done...

Comment: Sidenote: It's not PHP, that tells you, that there is an error, it's the mysql-server.

Comment: Thank you and dully noted I was in a bit of a hurry tipping this out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

'$table_name' should not be in quotes: it's a table name, not a string column value,

use backticks if you have to, but they aren't necessary

Comment: Only $table_name or all the others?

Comment: The column names 'Code' and 'Name' shouldn't be in quotes either, they're column names... you can use backticks ` if you need to for table/column names, but it's only necessary if your table/column names contain special characters such as spaces, or are MySQL reserved words. '$rank' and '$name' are string values, so they do need to be quoted

Comment: thank you this has worked I was so afraid of messing up the SQL synthax I copied exactly how phpmyadmin did it.

Comment: @GeorgeBora phpmyadmin uses backticks, indeed

Answer (score 3):

In MySQL quotes (`'`) are used to denote a string literal.

Backticks (`` ` ``) are used to denote MySQL 'objects' such as database names, table names and column names.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use quotation marks for table and column names. You can use backticks "`" instead or just leave the quotes out:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO `{$table_name}` (`Code`, `Name`) VALUES ('{$rank}', '{$name}')";
```

PS: Never **ever** insert an unsafe string variable like `$name=$_POST['name'];` directly into your SQL statements. This makes your application vulnerable against SQL injections. See here for more information: [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-stop-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Using mysqli or pdo prepared statements would be even better